# how to fix simple function with event hadlers

Tags: javascript

I'm only trying to iterate through a string every time a user clicks on a letter.

If the user clicks on a letter that its on the string. The letter should display on the screen, nut I'm having issues with my code, specifically on the event handler. Any suggestions?

```
 var view = {
    displayMessage : function (msg) {
        var messageArea = document.getElementById ("messageArea");
        messageArea.innerHTML = msg;
    },
    displayWord : function (word) {
        var areaword = document.getElementById ("word");
        areaword.innerHTML = word;
    },
};
window.onload = init;

var newWord = "quizzes";

function init () {

    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName ("input");

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

        buttons[i].onclick = showLetter;

    }
}
function showLetter (eventObj) {

    var value = eventObj.target.value;

    for (var i = 0; i < newWord.length; i++) {

        if (newWord.charAt (i) == = value) {

            view.displayMessage (value);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make a live demo on jsfiddle.net so we can see html and js together?

Comment: the code logic you present seems really confused.  What, in english, exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: So this is kinda like a game. Basically I have a variable with a value of “quizzez”. When the user clicks on a letter, I wanna iterate through “quizzez” and if the user guess right simply show that letter on the screen.